How to set up Amplitude with Riverpod generators?
I am using Riverpod for state management and want to set up Amplitude for tracking. I set up a provider using generators like so:
@riverpod
Amplitude amplitudeProvider(AmplitudeProviderRef ref) {
  final Amplitude amplitude = Amplitude.getInstance();
  amplitude.init(Env.amplitudeApiKey);
  return amplitude;
}

But when I try to read it with
final amplitude = ref.read(amplitudeProvider);

I get the error
The argument type 'Amplitude Function(ProviderRef)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ProviderListenable'.

When I set up the provider manually with code-generation everything works. But since you shouldn't mix generated and not generated providers, I am kind of in a pickle. Does anyone understand where this is coming from?
Works like this:
final amplitudeProvider = Provider<Amplitude>((ref) {
  final Amplitude amplitude = Amplitude.getInstance();
  amplitude.init(Env.amplitudeApiKey);
  return amplitude;
});


Don't forget to add :
part 'name_of_your_file.g.dart' at the top of the file
Then your method should be :
@riverpod
Amplitude amplitude(AmplitudeRef ref) {
  final Amplitude amplitude = Amplitude.getInstance();
  amplitude.init(Env.amplitudeApiKey);
  return amplitude;
}

The generator will then generate amplitudeProvider from your amplitude function.
After that ref.read(amplitudeProvider) should work !

Thanks. I did include the part file. That is not the reason for this issue.

@OleSpaarmann Yes, the reason is that your function is called amplitudeProvider but it should simply be called amplitude, amplitudeProvider will then be generated by riverpod_generator
